# How come cookie path doesn't take effect?

Tags: php, session, cookies, admin, sid

There are 2 projects under my Apache public_html root. One is "/project1" and the other is "/project2". Project 2 is just duplicate of project 1 but with some modification to fit a different goal. They have the same core code, so the session names used are the same.

I initialize session this way for project 1:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_path","/project1");
session_name("sid");
session_start();
```

And very similar for project 2:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_path","/project2");
session_name("sid");
session_start();
```

The cookie paths are not equal, so even with the same cookie name (here is 'sid'), PHP should be able to differentiate them.

But the fun is that when admin on project 1 logins, then the admin in project 2 is also interestingly logged in.

Comment: Works fine for me. Firefox shows two cookies with different paths and session IDs. /project1 can't see the contents of my session in /project2. Can you verify that your browser is creating separate cookies?

Comment: @Wiseguy tks for the suggestion, found it, everything is with the correct cookie path but there is only 1 single code line with the cookie path '/' hidding in a function i didn't look over. so everything became like at root

Comment: You should probably answer this yourself if you solved it. It will help future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browser don't like cookies with path and without expiration, so you can add:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600);
```

The session cookie is sent only one time by PHP (if missing), then to force PHP to resend the cookie, with updated expiration time, after **session_start()** you can add:

```
session_regenerate_id();
```